# How to switch MiniBufExplorer tabs in VIM when connecting with xterm?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, vim, xterm

I just installed MiniBufExplorer in VIM on an Ubuntu server, to which I'm connecting using xterm from a Mac (via ssh).

From what I gather, after giving the command `:set mouse=a` I can use the mouse in general, an in particular to double-click the tabs in order to switch between them. This works when I'm using the Ubuntu Terminal (via VNC), but not through the Mac's xterm. The simple mouse control *does* work from the xterm, but not the double-clicks for switching between tabs.

I'd love to know:

1. Is there a keyboard commands for switching between the MiniBufExplorer tabs?
2. Is there a way to get the double-clicks to work on the xterm?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try Ubuntu: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/

or Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 8):

You can also jump to a buffer by referencing its number, e.g. :b1  :b2 :b3 etc...

Comment: This is way more useful than mouse commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Bind keys to `:MBEbn<CR>` and `:MBEbp<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set a few other things. From my .vimrc:

```
set mouse=a " Enable the mouse
set ttymouse=xterm2
behave xterm
set selectmode=mouse
```

I can work with tabs etc. on remote systems just fine with these settings.

Comment: Thanks! just the "set ttymouse=xterm2" did the trick for me.
However, do you know what about the keyboard commands for switching the tabs?

Comment: I think for minibufexplorer if you put the cursor on a tab name and press "Enter" it switches. <tab> key cycles through, so you go <tab><tab><enter> and so on. You can also click on the one you want then press enter.